# Взаимодействие с драйвером через файл

Tags: linux, драйвер, kernel

*Нужно написать драйвер поддерживающий чтение файла в формате ASCII и запись
сообщений в него через пользовательский процесс: `ioctl_set_msg(file_desc,
msg)`. Поддерживает функцию удаления сообщения: `ioctl_msg_delete`.*

Не подскажите, как открыть файл в адресном пространстве ядра, прочитать/записать сообщения в него, и передать ioctl? Нашёл статью «[Глава 6. Работа с файлами устройств](http://www.crossplatform.ru/?q=node/342)» с примером, но там всё происходит напрямую с устройством, а не через файл.

Comment: Очень плохо описана постановка задачи. Чтение файлов из ядра, тем более с заранее неизвестной ФС — это плохой дизайн.

Answer (score 1):

В книге "Программирование модулей ядра Linux", Олег Цилюрик, так описывается эта возможность:

> Операции с данными в именованных файлах (разных: регулярных файлах,
>   FIFO и др.) не относятся к тем возможностям, которыми код ядра
>   (модуля) должен активно пользоваться, для того не видно оснований
>   (так же, например, как и операциями с абсолютным хронологическим
>   временем). Но, во-первых, такие операции вполне возможны, а во-вторых,
>   существует, как минимум, одна ситуация, когда такая возможность
>   насущно необходима: это чтение конфигурационных данных модуля (при
>   запуске) их его конфигурационных файлов.

Там даже приводится небольшой пример:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static const char inp_file[] = "/etc/yumex.profiles.conf";
#define BUF_LEN 255
static int __init kread_init( void ) {
   struct file *f;
   char buff[ BUF_LEN + 1 ];
   size_t n;

   printk( KERN_ALERT "**** openning file: %s\n", inp_file );
   f = filp_open( inp_file, O_RDONLY, 0 );
   if( !f ) {
      printk( KERN_ALERT "file open failed: %s\n",inp_file );
      return -ENOENT;
   }

   n = kernel_read( f, 0, buff, BUF_LEN );
   if( n ) {
       printk( KERN_ALERT "**** read first %d bytes:\n", n );
       buff[ n ] = '\0';
       printk( KERN_ALERT "%s\n", buff );
   } else {
       printk( KERN_ALERT "kernel_read failed\n" );
       return -EIO;
   }

   printk( KERN_ALERT "**** close file: %s\n", inp_file );

   filp_close( f, NULL );
   return -EPERM;
}

module_init( kread_init );
MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL" );
```